# String Compression: Passing Object Through URL

Tags: java, json, object, compression, url-parameters

I have two pages, say A and B. User navigates from Page-A to Page-B. Page-B needs to have some values which are passed from the Page-A. Among these values some of them are Objects. Now I have the following ways to pass the parameter to Page-B

- Store the Objects in some Scope (say Session, Page-Flow).
- Pass the Objects as query string after converting them into String.

The drawbacks of the above two ways are followings respectively:

- If User bookmarks the Page-B for later usage and try to access it from different session, it generates Exception. As the Objects are not present in the scope.
- There are limitations of the length of the URL, which is 2048 Character ([ref](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html)). So if I convert it to JSON and try to pass it through URL and if the JSON String is more than the limited characters, I would get JSON Exception from Page-B.

Can I compress the String representation of the Object so that it will not exceed the limitation Character?

How can I solve this issue (by any other means)?

Any solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either store them and pass IDs as GET parameters or post the objects. Or use a cookie.

Comment: One usually avoids the URL lenght limitation by using the POST method instead of standard GET, then the parameter part of the URL moves to the message body part of the HTTP request.

Comment: What kind of objects are you passing in the URL? I mean what is their use? Do they represent session information or static information like user preferences? If session scope then if user tries to use bookmarked url you should redirect the user to log in again before using those objects. Well I am not a web expert, but this is how I look at it. Maybe you can use Cookies.

Comment: @mvw But GET is a *safe* method whereas POST isn't. There is good reason to want to keep GET. Of course, the server must comply with these semantics for this distinction to be meaningful in the first place.

Comment: @mvw this would not help user to access the page if he/she bookmarked it.

Comment: Regarding string compression: That is depending on the string contents and thus not predictable, I would not go that route. Better persist your stuff and hand out IDs as @AntP suggested.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik What exactly do you mean by safe?

Comment: @mvw It's an HTTP standard's official term. It means it can safely be repeated without unwanted state changes on the server. GET is also cacheable, which is another advantage.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for providing the context. Now your comments make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting serialized objects in the URL is a really bad idea.  If you want to access state via URL (GET parameters) then normally the URL should only contain some way of identifying the item in question.

Fortunately if you're using a database back end to persist your objects then the database will usually give them an identity for you, in the form of a primary key.  You can then just put the ID in the URL and have Java retrieve the object for that ID whenever it receives a request for it.

If you don't use a database back end then it's up to you to give your objects an identity that they can be located by.  The simplest solution would be to store references to the objects in a map and put the map key in the URL.

Comment: Then you have to know when to clean up the map

Comment: @nafg Yes you do, and that's a far less troublesome problem than ensuring serialised data in the URL isn't corrupted or deliberately manipulated to be malicious.